# export grid view to excel using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I have created  a page which will accept SharePoint list name as query string and generate an excel file

I am trying to export to excel using the below code

```
ListName = ListName.Replace(" ", "");
string attachment = "attachment; filename=" + ListName + ".xls";
HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default;
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel 8.0";
HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = "";
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter htmlwriter = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
gridview.DataSource = _dtFramedTable;
gridview.DataBind();

htmlwriter.AddAttribute("xmlns:x", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel");
htmlwriter.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Html);
htmlwriter.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Head);
htmlwriter.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Style);
htmlwriter.Write("br {mso-data-placement:same-cell;}");
htmlwriter.RenderEndTag();
htmlwriter.RenderEndTag();
htmlwriter.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Body);
gridview.RenderControl(htmlwriter);
htmlwriter.RenderEndTag();
htmlwriter.RenderEndTag();
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(sw.ToString()));
HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
HttpContext.Current.Response.Close();
```

This exports gridview to excel, but when I open the excel file, it says

> file format and extension of don't match. the file could be corrupted
>   or unsafe unless you trust the source, don't open it

How can this be avoided?

Comment: Why are you using a HtmlTextWriter?

Comment: I will call this page as a iframefile using C# in sharepoint visual webpart

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\""+Export.xls+"\"; filename*=UTF-8''"+Uri.EscapeDataString(Export.xls)); );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", "example.xls"))
```

Comment: While this might be right, maybe a line of explanation would help the poster to understand, why this helps him.

Comment: i tried changing this, but the warning message is still coming